# Magento MyGate Payment Gateway

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

We have a Magento site (http://www.bigblue.co.za) that makes use of MyGate (been customised) as a payment gateway. We have a problem here, when a user checkout on our site and choose credit card as a payment method, the order has been placed. The order waits for a respond from MyGate regarding the 3D secure authorisation.

The payment should be settled once the payment has been authorised which it does, but what I don't understand is, why when the authorisation has failed the order status on Magento does become Canceled but it still settles the payment in Magento saying Total Paid = Amount and not Total Paid = R0.00. This issue is causing stock qty not to be restored when the order has been cancelled because total paid is paid when it is not.

Is this a coding issue in Magento or an issue on MyGate's side when responding back to Magento?

Comment: I've checked some of the Pending Payment orders just now that used Credit Card as the payment method, although the status is Pending Payment, the Total Paid = Amount instead of Total Paid = R0.00.
This is really becoming a big issue now.

Please can someone help me with this

Thank you.

Comment: what is the status of this issue have you managed to sort it?